# Xarrow not updating when I scroll down

Tags: reactjs, next.js, drag-and-drop, draggable, xarrows

I'm using Xarrow in a react project to connect between draggable components, the problem is that when I drag a component down and scroll to see it, the arrow doesn't update and it stays in it's initial position (even tho it updates when a component is dragged)

here's how my DraggableBox was called :

```
const Canvas = (props) => {
        <Xwrapper className='overflow-auto '>
        <DraggableBox id={'piece1'} options={props.options} prev={props.prev} title={props.title} overlay={props.overlay } videosrc={props.videosrc} />
        <DraggableBox id={'piece2'} options={props.options} prev={props.prev} title={props.title} overlay={props.overlay } videosrc={props.videosrc}/>
        <DraggableBox id={'piece3'} options={props.options} prev={props.prev} title={props.title} overlay={props.overlay } videosrc={props.videosrc}/>
        <Xarrow start={'piece1'} end={'piece2'} showHead={false} color="black" startAnchor='bottom' endAnchor='top'  />
        <Xarrow start={'piece1'} end={'piece3'} showHead={false} color="black" startAnchor='bottom' endAnchor='top'  />
      </Xwrapper>

    )
}

export default Canvas;
```

and here's my DDraggableBox :

```
const DraggableBox = ({id,options,prev,title,overlay,videosrc}) => {
  const updateXarrow = useXarrow();
  return (
      <Draggable onDrag={updateXarrow} onStop={updateXarrow} >
          <div id={id} className="w-fit h-fit">
          <ScenarioPiece  options={options} prev={prev} title={title} overlay={overlay} videosrc={videosrc}  />
          </div>
      </Draggable>
  );
};
```